# What is std::filesystem::remove_all() supposed to do with an empty path?

Tags: c++, filesystems, is-empty, delete-directory

I wonder, what is supposed to happen with a call such as this?

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::remove_all({});
    return 0;
}
```

I guess [`path::empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/empty) implies that my argument is an empty path, but [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) does not have anything that I recognize as useful regarding empty paths.

Comment: Most likely it will try to do `rm ""`, which will fail and throw exception. Though it's a bit of a guess, cppreference is not very clear on how empty paths works.

Comment: I would expect an empty path to be an invalid path and the underlying API to fail on it, causing an exception to be thrown or an `error_code` to be returned, depending on which overload you call

Comment: You are absolutely right @bers. I have done extensive research and I discovered that boost::filesystem from which std::filesystem was adapted has a clear explanation of what an empty path is. **An empty path is an empty path indeed**. It is represented by `""` (empty string) in the literal sense. And an empty path doesn’t exist as a real path on the filesystem of the OS. One upvote from me. Good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal form of an empty path is an empty path. It is represented by `""` (empty string) in the literal sense. And an empty path doesn’t exist as a *real path* on the filesystem of the OS. You can test this with:

```cpp
std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::path{}); /* <—- will return false */
```

---

The program code in the OP

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::remove_all({});
    return 0;
}
```

Will therefore be expected to behave according to the specification in the standard:

> **Remove all**
>
> ```
> uintmax_t remove_all(const path& p);
> ```
>
> ```
> uintmax_t remove_all(const path& p, error_code& ec);
> ```
>
> 1. *Effects:* Recursively deletes the contents of `p` ***if it exists***, then deletes file `p` itself, as if by POSIX `remove()`. [Note: A symbolic link is itself removed, rather than the file it resolves to. —end note]
> 2. *Postconditions:* exists(symlink_status(p)) is false.
> 3. *Returns:* The number of files removed. The signature with argument `ec` returns `static_cast<uintmax_t>(-1)` if an error occurs.
>
> —-ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N4860 29.11.14.31

Since `std::filesystem::path{}` doesn’t exist on the OS, the return value of

```cpp
std::filesystem::remove_all({});
```

Will be `0`. No files will be removed.