# How does the C++ standard specify that empty paths should be normalized?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std-filesystem

This question is related to another one asked [here <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78041557/16770846)<sup>1</sup>. The *C++20 standard* outlines the procedure for the *”Normalization of a generic format pathname”* (cpp reference uses the wording: A path can be normalized by following this algorithm. See [`std::filesystem::path` <sup>[cpp-reference]</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path))

> 6 Normalization of a generic format pathname means:
>
> 1. ***If the path is empty, stop.***
> 2. Replace each slash character in the root-name with a preferred-separator.
> 3. Replace each directory-separator with a preferred-separator. [Note: The generic pathname grammar (29.11.7.1) defines directory-separator as one or more slashes and preferred-separators. —end note]
> 4. Remove each dot filename and any immediately following directory-separator.
> 5. As long as any appear, remove a non-dot-dot filename immediately followed by a directory-separator and a dot-dot filename, along with any immediately following directory-separator.
> 6. If there is a root-directory, remove all dot-dot filenames and any directory-separators immediately following them. [Note: These dot-dot filenames attempt to refer to nonexistent parent directories. —end note]
> 7. If the last filename is dot-dot, remove any trailing directory-separator.
> 8. ***If the path is empty, add a dot.***
>
> The result of normalization is a path in normal form, which is said to be normalized.
>
> —-ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N4860 29.11.7.1

Now my question is: “if the path is empty and the ‘algorithm’ stops as outlined in **step 1**, how will **step 8** then be fulfilled by the ‘algorithm’?”

---

<sub>1. Disclaimer! The answer there is mine but even I with my answer am no longer convinced.</sub>

Comment: If the path is empty, there is nothing to normalize, so the algorithm will stop. Stopping means it will not proceed any further. Thus, step 8 will never be reached in that case, of course. Step 8 talks about the path being empty after the previous steps have been executed, not in the case when it was already empty in the first step.

Comment: So is the text you quoted above actually in the standard?  Looks like you pulled it from cppreference which is *not* the standard.

Comment: @MarkRansom It is from the standard, as indicated at the end of the quote: https://eel.is/c++draft/input.output#fs.path.generic-6

Comment: @heapunderrun what then is the rationale if step 1 handles the same case?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Step 1 handles the case when the path is initially empty. Supposedly, in that case, the algorithm must not convert it to a `.` (probably because an empty path is invalid anyway, so normalization should not convert it to a valid one, I assume). Step 8, on the other hand, handles the case when the path becomes empty after some previous step(s), and thus this applies only when the initial path was not empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is: “if the path is empty and the ‘algorithm’ stops as outlined in step 1, **how will step 8 then be fulfilled** by the ‘algorithm’?”

It won't. As the path is empty and there is nothing to normalize and the algorithm has been stopped at step 1 as a consequence.

Comment: Fair enough. But why is there a step 8 and why is it still handling the same case of empty path?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Step 8 is not handling _the same_ case. There is even an example (in parentheses) in the description of Step 8 on Cppreference: _"normal form of `./` is `.`"_, it says. So, if the initial path to be normalized is `./` then the algorithm eventually proceeds to Step 4: _"Remove each dot and any immediately following directory-separator."_ This produces an empty path. So, at Step 8, it needs to add a dot. This is one of the cases when Step 8 is needed.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Another one would be `somedir/../`, for example: if this would be the initial path then Step 5 would remove the "non-dot-dot filename", which is `somedir`, along with `/../` that follows, thus rendering the path empty. Now Step 8 would kick in, adding the `.`. Basically, Step 8 handles cases when the path eventually _becomes_ empty, not the case when the path is initially empty.